# Need a help on logs with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have used codeigniter framework.Have used its log part.
I had a query regarding configuring logs in the application.
As per the documentation they say that we can configure in app/config/php and filter the logs as debug,error or info messages.
But even after doing that, I am not able to filter the logs.
Wanted to know the reason for this or am i missing something.
Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have changed that from 4 to 0 but still all logs are coming and its not getting filtered as only error messages.
Do i need to do any other configuration apart from this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the following steps to keep log file.

1. Change the following line of your `application/config/config.php` file

   ```
   $config['log_threshold'] = 4;
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   $config['log_threshold'] = 0;
   ```

This change will produce a log file in your `application/logs` directory with current date as file name.

Now if you want to write your custom log in this log file then write the following code:

```
log_message('ERROR','YOUR_MESSAGE_HERE');
```

Here you can use 'ERROR', 'DEBUG' etc.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Have changed that from 4 to 0 but still all logs are coming and its not getting filtered as only error messages.
Do i need to do any other configuration apart from this?

Comment: Do you want only the ERROR message?

Comment: Then just use `$config['log_threshold'] = 1;` Please read the Codeigniter documentation well first.

Comment: According to documentation have changed the threshhold value to 1 but that doesnt seem to be working...its not filtering logs